# PySpark code structure

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am writing PySpark code where I have 10 look up tables and for eah lookup table, I define a struct and then a schema. I then create a DF for each lookup table and use them to join with one main table in the end.  I know how to code but please can someone guide me how to structure the code?I am new to Python so don't know how to organize my code in PySpark. Maybe share me some sample production PySpark code? Thanks!

Comment: You should first show your code, but StackOverflow is for fixing problems, usually, not reviewing or providing "production code". For that, try [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Just wanted to know what the best practices are to structure the code for PySpark.

Comment: Sounds opinion-based, which is off-topic here unfortunately. Why can't the best practice be something that works? As I've said, refactoring should be posted at code review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For resuing and managing your code you can define different parts in a different class.
My approach is to create an `ini` or `yaml` as reference.
also, you can handle input variables in test and production environments.

for example:

main class:

```py
from sparkSchema import SparkSchema
from configparser import ConfigParser 

if __name__ == "__main__":

    config_path = './config.ini'
    config = ConfigParser()
    config.optionxform = str
    config.read(config_path)

#initialize your app, create session and context, etc. 
#also you can handle this part with some class.

streamDFWithSchema  = SparkSchema(streamDF, config, 'Schema').getDFWithSchema()

# rest of the code
```

It's good to define each input variable (for example Schema in SparkSchema class) as an input variable and you can use `argpars` library.I have not used in this example.

SparkSchema class:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_timestamp

class SparkSchema:
    
    def __init__(self, DF, config, section):
        self.DF =DF
        self.config = config
        self.section = section


    def getDFWithSchema(self):
        
        self.DF  = self.DF \
      .selectExpr(
   'CAST(split(KafkaValue,"'+self.config[self.section]['message.delimiter']+'")['
   +self.config[self.section]['grouped.column.index']+
   '] AS STRING) as '+self.config[self.section]['grouped.column.name'] \
   ,'CAST(split(KafkaValue,"'+self.config[self.section]['message.delimiter']+'")['
   +self.config[self.section]['date.column.index']+
   '] AS STRING) as '+self.config[self.section]['date.column.name'])

        self.DF = self.DF\
            .withColumn('EventDate',
            to_timestamp(self.config[self.section]['date.column.name']
            , self.config[self.section]['date.column.format']))
        self.DF.printSchema()
        return self.DF
```

`.ini` file:

```
.
.
.
[Schema]
message.delimiter=\\\|
grouped.column.name=EmployeeId
grouped.column.index=61
date.column.name=END_DATE
date.column.index=12
date.column.format=yyyyMMddHHmmss
[SchemaLocal]
message.delimiter=\\\|
grouped.column.name=EmployeeId
grouped.column.index=2
date.column.name=END_DATE
date.column.index=3
date.column.format=yyyy-MM-dd HHmmss
.
.
.
```

and you should add library `configparser` as `--py-files` in your spark-submit command:

```sh
$ spark-submit --jars some.jar,jar.file\
  --py-files configparser.zip,argpars.zip\
  main_class.py
```